# Child process opening unexpected electron windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm with a problem after using electron-builder or electron-packager, I belive that the problem is at asar. If I execute the code with `electron .` it works nicely, but if I build an executable with electron-builder or electron-packager, when I call a child process it opens another instance of the program, and don't do what was expected.

### With electron .

When I click on "Converter" button it starts to convert the .xml files to PDFs as expected.

### Built version

[before click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nugsg.png)

[after click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdU7Z.png)

### Code

***Click:***

```
e.onclick = () => {

  let path = document.getElementById("pasta").files[0].path.replace(/\\/g, '/');

  let c1 = cp.spawn(process.execPath, [__dirname + '/child.js'], {
  stdio: ['inherit', 'inherit', 'inherit', 'ipc']
});

  c1.send(path);

  c1.on('message', m => {
    if(m.name === 'start') {
      document.getElementById("start").className += " disabled";
    }
    if(m.name === 'process') {
      document.getElementById("bar").style.width = m.data + "%";
    }
    if(m.name === 'end') {
      document.getElementById("start").className = document.getElementById("start").className.replace(" disabled", '');
      document.getElementById("bar").style.width = "0%";
      window.alert("Conversão relizada com sucesso!");
    }
  });
}
```

***Child.js***

```
'use strict';
const pdf = require('../pdfCreator.js');
const timer = require('timers');

process.on('message', m => {
  let path = m;
  process.send({name: 'start'});
  pdf.readDir(path, status => {
    let percent = parseInt((status.now/status.total) * 100);
    process.send({name: 'process', data: percent});
  }, () => {
    timer.setTimeout(() => {
      process.send({name:'end'});
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

Comment: Git repo: [link](https://github.com/gabrielcarneiro97/nota-reader)

Comment: I've tried to put the child spawn outside the click function, the result was an infinite number of windows beeing open.

Comment: I've tried to set the cwd to __dirname, didn't work as well.

Comment: I've discovered that process.executePath it's beeing set as the executable generated by de packager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How I soved this

I realised that is child process don't work at asar packages, so I changed the child process to a background window where I can run the functions without freeze the UI  (that was the reason why I was trying to use child process), in the end it worked as a child process.

#### Code

**Main.js**

```
  win.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'app/index.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
  }));

  backgroundWin = new BrowserWindow({show: false});

  backgroundWin.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'app/process.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
  }));

  ipcMain.on('toUi', (e, m) => {
    win.webContents.send('message', m);
  });

  ipcMain.on('toProcessor', (e, m) => {
    backgroundWin.webContents.send('message', m);
  });
```

**Processor.js**

```
ipcRenderer.on('message', (e, m) => {

  if(m.type === 'start'){
    let path = m.data;
    ipcRenderer.send('toUi', {type: 'start'});
    pdf.readDir(path, status => {
      let percent = parseInt((status.now/status.total) * 100);
      ipcRenderer.send('toUi', {type: 'process', data: percent});
    }, () => {
      timer.setTimeout(() => {
        ipcRenderer.send('toUi', {type:'end'});
      }, 1000);
    });
  }

});
```

**UI.js**

```
ipcRenderer.on('message', (e, m) => {
      console.log(m);
      if(m.type === 'start') {
        document.getElementById("start").className += " disabled";
      }
      if(m.type === 'process') {
        document.getElementById("bar").style.width = m.data + "%";
      }
      if(m.type === 'end') {
        document.getElementById("start").className = document.getElementById("start").className.replace(" disabled", '');
        document.getElementById("bar").style.width = "0%";
        window.alert("Conversão relizada com sucesso!");
      }
});
```

So I send a message to the main and the main sends to the UI or to the backgroud process and it work as magic.

[Git repo](https://github.com/gabrielcarneiro97/nota-reader).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be spawning process.execPath, normally you would be spawning "node".

```
let c1 = cp.spawn('node', [__dirname + '/child.js'], {
  stdio: ['inherit', 'inherit', 'inherit', 'ipc']
}
```

Comment: Spawn with 'node' works well at the production, but at the built one it don't spawn the child, nothing happens.

Comment: I've tried with 'node.exe' as well and still not working.

Comment: check your __dirname to see if another part of the app has changed your working directory, also try having stdout and stderr logs to display any problems that may arise